# Why can't I plot my model selection plot correctly?

Tags: r, plot, regression

I am working with multiple regression models. After running the dredge function, I got approximately 54 000 different combinations. I selected the first 300 models and ran this code:

```
par(mar=c(1,4,10,3))
> plot(fitt, labels = c("Intercept",
+                       "YOFE",
+                       "'RW Closeness'",
+                       "'LW Closeness'",
+                       "Age",
+                       "SES",
+                       "'GAD-7 Score'",
+                       "Fantasy",
+                       "'Personal Distress'",
+                       "'Empathic Concern'",
+                       "'Perspective Taking'",
+                       "'PHQ-9 Score'",
+                       "'Religioius Affinity'",
+                       "'Agreement with IH'",
+                       "'Moral Judgement of IH'",
+                       "'Harm Assessment of IH'",
+                       "'Agreement with IB'",
+                       "'Moral Judgement of IB'",
+                       "RMET",
+                       "Sex"),ylab = expression("Cumulative" ~italic(w[i]*(AICc))),col = c(colfunc(1)), border = "gray30",labAsExpr = TRUE)
```

10 minutes later, I got this error:

> Error in (function (text, side = 3, line = 0, outer = FALSE, at = NA,  :
> zero-length 'text' specified
> In addition: Warning message:
> In max(strwidth(arg[["text"]], cex = arg$cex, units = "in")) :
> no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

And this is the output plot:

[image: This is the output plot]

I've tried plotting only the first model and the same error appears:

[image: the same error appears]

This also happens when using the whole model selection table (54 000 combinations).

What is a solution to this?

I'm running the latest version of R and RStudio on my 2016 12 inch Macbook.

Note: I've tried increasing the plot-window size manually by dragging the edges without any improvement.

This is what I'd like my plot to look like:

[image: This is what I'd like my plot to look like]

EDIT: Here is the data file [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18-ARlJeTHUqQhqBHjkq8u4LGSWWFrmED/view?usp=sharing) and the code.

```
modeloglobal<-lm(PROMEDIO_CREENCIA_NFALSA_CORONAVIRUS~Edad+Sex+
             AnEdu+
             Estrato_1+
             GAD_TOTAL+
             PHQ_TOTAL+
             PracticRel_2+
             CercanPolDer_1+
             CercanPolIz_1+
             RMET_TOTAL+
             IRI_PREOCUPACIÓN_EMPATICA+
             IRI_FANTASÍA+
             IRI_MALESTAR_PERSONAL+
             IRI_TOMA_DE_PERSPECTIVA+
             PROMEDIO_DILEMAS_BI_ACTUARIGUAL_CORONAVIRUS+
             PROMEDIO_DILEMAS_BI_BIENOMAL_CORONAVIRUS+
             PROMEDIO_DI_SINPOL_ACTUARIGUAL+
             PROMEDIO_DI_SINPOL_BIENOMAL+
             PROMEDIO_DI_SINPOL_DANO, data=fake_news,na.action="na.fail")


        library(MuMIn)
fitt<-dredge(modeloglobal,trace=2)
    m.sel <- model.sel(fitt)
m.sel2 <- m.sel[1:300,]
library(binovisualfields)
```

And the code that runs the error (using a subset of the first 300 rows):

```
par(mar=c(1,4,10,3))
> plot(m.sel2, labels = c("Intercept",
+                       "YOFE",
+                       "'RW Closeness'",
+                       "'LW Closeness'",
+                       "Age",
+                       "SES",
+                       "'GAD-7 Score'",
+                       "Fantasy",
+                       "'Personal Distress'",
+                       "'Empathic Concern'",
+                       "'Perspective Taking'",
+                       "'PHQ-9 Score'",
+                       "'Religioius Affinity'",
+                       "'Agreement with IH'",
+                       "'Moral Judgement of IH'",
+                       "'Harm Assessment of IH'",
+                       "'Agreement with IB'",
+                       "'Moral Judgement of IB'",
+                       "RMET",
+                       "Sex"),ylab = expression("Cumulative" ~italic(w[i]*(AICc))),col = c(colfunc(1)), border = "gray30",labAsExpr = TRUE)
```

EDIT 2: Here's the data frame I got from dput().

```
             ResponseId Edad    Sex    Genero   Nacion    Resid Estrato_1       Gastos salud
1 R_25GEak825Ohmb9G   18 Female  Femenino Colombia Colombia         7     Seguro privado
2 R_1kT7u0PALDHV8H6   20 Female  Femenino Colombia Colombia         5     Seguro privado
3 R_2cpBb5Ifzj7lVGs   21 Female  Femenino Colombia Colombia         6     Seguro privado
4 R_sGqNUMTXTJzwC09   20   Male Masculino Colombia Colombia         5  Seguro del Estado
5 R_2Cpixt9Z5FJkhg1   36   Male Masculino Colombia Colombia         6 Otro (especifique)
6 R_3QFq50SZNs6CePA   18 Female  Femenino Colombia Colombia         7     Seguro privado
                       Relig PracticRel_2 AnEdu                        Q161 Ecron Epsiq Q183 Eneu Q184
1                    Ninguna            0    15                  Estudiante     1     0 <NA>    0 <NA>
2 Cristianismo (Catolicismo)            2    15                  Estudiante     0     0 <NA>    0 <NA>
3 Cristianismo (Catolicismo)            2    19                  Estudiante     0     0 <NA>    0 <NA>
4 Cristianismo (Catolicismo)            2    15                  Estudiante     0     0 <NA>    0 <NA>
5 Cristianismo (Catolicismo)            1    17 Empleado de tiempo completo     0     0 <NA>    0 <NA>
6 Cristianismo (Catolicismo)            4    15                  Estudiante     0     0 <NA>    0 <NA>
  NPviven Sustancias          Pviven AdhAS LevantarAS_1 CumplimAS_1                HorasFuera
1       1          1          Padres     1            5           6         Menos de una hora
2       3          0 Padres,Hermanos     1            1           6         Menos de una hora
3       4          0 Padres,Hermanos     1            2           6         Menos de una hora
4       4          0 Padres,Hermanos     1            2           6         Menos de una hora
5       3          0    Pareja,Hijos     1            2           3 Entre cuatro y seis horas
6       3          0 Padres,Hermanos     1            2           6    Entre una y tres horas
  Apoyo CV19_1 ContagUd ContagEC Prob_1_contagio Prob_2_familiar_contagio
1            1       No        0              81                      100
2            4       No        0              81                       35
3            6       No        0              60                       80
4            4       No        0               4                       15
5            5       No        0              40                       40
6            6       No        0              79                       86
  Prob_3_contagio_poblaciongeneral Caract_1 Caract_2 Inv_3 Caract_3 Caract_4 Caract_5 Caract_6 Caract_8
1                               87        4        2     1        6        4        5        4        5
2                               81        5        4     3        4        4        5        2        3
3                               80        4        4     1        6        6        6        1        2
4                               20        6        5     5        2        1        5        1        5
5                               60        2        1     2        5        4        3        2        3
6                               70        5        4     2        5        6        2        5        6
  Caract_9 Caract_11 Caract_14 INV_15 Caract_15 Caract_16 Caract_17 CompPan_1 CompPan_2 CompPan_3
1        5         3         2      4         3         5         5         1         6         1
2        4         5         4      5         2         3         3         4         5         8
3        6         1         6      6         1         6         6         1         1         1
4        5         5         2      6         1         3         1         1         3         2
5        4         1         1      5         2         2         2         2         2         2
6        6         2         3      5         2         6         5         2         7         3
  CompPan_4 CompPan_5 CompPan_6 CercanPolDer_1 CercanPolIz_1 IDpol_1 PHQ_TOTAL GAD_TOTAL
1         5         5         7              8             2       5         8         6
2         8         8         8              7             3       5         4         3
3         3         2         4              6             3       4         2         3
4         4         3         3              5             5       4         3         3
5         3         3         2              5             5       4         2         2
6         6         2         7              3             8       3         7         7
  INTEROCEPCION_TOTAL BIS BAS_FUN_SEEKING BAS_REWARD_RESPONSIVENESS BAS_DRIVE BAS_TOTAL
1                  45  19              14                        19        11        44
2                  44  20              10                        17        14        41
3                  24  17              10                        19        13        42
4                  17  17               9                        14         8        31
5                  36  21              10                        17        11        38
6                  41  25               6                        17        13        36
  IRI_TOMA_DE_PERSPECTIVA IRI_MALESTAR_PERSONAL IRI_FANTASÍA IRI_PREOCUPACIÓN_EMPATICA RMET_TOTAL
1                      14                    13           14                        19          7
2                      18                    11           14                        20          4
3                      17                     4           10                        20         10
4                      16                     9           11                        12          7
5                      10                    11            7                        10         10
6                      16                    11           16                        18          8
  PROMEDIO_TIEMPO_REACCION_RMET PROMEDIO_CREENCIA_NFALSA_TODAS PROMEDIO_CREENCIA_NFALSA_CORONAVIRUS
1                      2.411750                            2.8                             2.666667
2                      3.348500                            2.8                             2.333333
3                      3.261083                            2.4                             2.000000
4                      6.390500                            2.2                             1.666667
5                     13.212667                            1.8                             1.333333
6                      4.218583                            3.6                             2.666667
  PROMEDIO_CREENCIA_NFALSA_OTRO PROMEDIO_TIEMPOREACCION_NFALSA PROMEDIO_CREENCIA_NVERDADERA_TODAS
1                           3.0                         4.3438                           3.333333
2                           3.5                         9.4222                           3.000000
3                           3.0                         5.9734                           3.666667
4                           3.0                        10.1448                           2.666667
5                           2.5                        16.3196                           1.333333
6                           5.0                         7.1954                           3.333333
  PROMEDIO_CREENCIA_NVERDADERA_CORONAVIRUS PROMEDIO_CREENCIA_NVERDADERA_OTRO
1                                        5                                 5
2                                        4                                 5
3                                        6                                 5
4                                        5                                 3
5                                        1                                 3
6                                        6                                 4
  PROMEDIO_TIEMPOREACCION_NVERDADERA PROMEDIO_CREENCIA_NMISLEADING_TODAS
1                             5.6440                            2.666667
2                             7.0430                            2.666667
3                             8.0265                            3.666667
4                             4.0495                            3.000000
5                            32.2400                            1.666667
6                             9.5830                            4.333333
  PROMEDIO_TIEMPOREACCION_NMISLEADING PROMEDIO_DILEMAS_BI_BIENOMAL_CORONAVIRUS
1                            5.726667                                 1.000000
2                           12.012333                                 4.000000
3                            5.753000                                 4.333333
4                            4.969667                                 1.333333
5                           15.233000                                 0.000000
6                           30.045667                                 3.666667
  PROMEDIO_DILEMAS_BI_ACTUARIGUAL_CORONAVIRUS DILEMA_BI_CONTROL_BIENOMAL DILEMA_BI_CONTROL_ACTUARIGUAL
1                                    5.666667                          4                             7
2                                    7.666667                          5                             4
3                                    9.666667                          2                             6
4                                    4.333333                          0                             2
5                                    3.666667                         -3                             2
6                                    9.333333                          4                            10
  PROMEDIO_DILEMAS_BI_BIENOMAL_JUNTOS PROMEDIO_DILEMAS_BI_ACTUARIGUAL_JUNTOS
1                                1.75                                   6.00
2                                4.25                                   6.75
3                                3.75                                   8.75
4                                1.00                                   3.75
5                               -0.75                                   3.25
6                                3.75                                   9.50
  PROMEDIO_DILEMAS_DI_BIENOMAL PROMEDIO_DILEMAS_DI_ACTUARIGUAL PROMEDIO_DILEMAS_DI_DANO
1                    0.5000000                        6.666667                 5.666667
2                    1.8333333                        7.666667                 6.166667
3                    0.5000000                        5.666667                 5.333333
4                    1.6666667                        5.000000                 5.500000
5                    0.8333333                        4.833333                 5.666667
6                    0.1666667                        5.166667                 7.000000
  TIEMPOREACCION_DILEMAS_DI TIEMPOREACCION_DILEMAS_BI PROMEDIO_DI_SINPOL_BIENOMAL
1                 12.140500                   7.89900                         0.2
2                  9.130667                   9.99550                         1.2
3                  6.998333                   9.25175                        -1.0
4                  1.857833                   2.84125                         0.4
5                 19.014333                  32.82850                         0.8
6                 11.633667                  16.92000                         0.2
  PROMEDIO_DI_SINPOL_ACTUARIGUAL PROMEDIO_DI_SINPOL_DANO COMPRAS_COVID19 PERCEPCION_RIESGO_TOTAL
1                           7.00                    7.25        4.166667                      39
2                           8.00                    6.75        6.833333                      37
3                           4.25                    7.25        2.000000                      42
4                           4.50                    7.00        2.666667                      38
5                           5.00                    7.75        2.333333                      26
6                           5.50                    7.75        4.500000                      46
  PERCEPCION_RIESGO_INDICE PROB_CONTAGIO_TOTAL PROMEDIO_DILEMASPOLITICOS_BIENOMAL
1                      3.9            89.33333                                1.0
2                      3.7            65.66667                                2.5
3                      4.2            73.33333                                4.0
4                      3.8            13.00000                                4.0
5                      2.6            46.66667                                0.5
6                      4.6            78.33333                                0.0
  PROMEDIO_DILEMASPOLITICOS_ACTUARIGUAL PROMEDIO_DILEMASPOLITICOS_DANO D31_1_DI D32_2_DI D33_3_DI
1                                   6.0                            2.5       -2        4        9
2                                   7.0                            5.0        3        9        7
3                                   8.5                            1.5       -3        3        8
4                                   6.0                            2.5        0        3        8
5                                   4.5                            1.5       -2        4        8
6                                   4.5                            5.5        4        9        7
  D41_1_DI D42_2_DI D43_3_DI D51_1_DI D52_2_DI D53_3_DI D61_1_DI D62_2_DI D63_3_DI D71_1_DIP D72_2_DIP
1       -1        7        7        5       10        4       -1        7        9         0         4
2        1        8        9        0        7        4        2        8        7         3         7
3        0        6        7        1        5        6       -3        3        8         3         7
4        0        5        8        4        7        3       -2        3        9         4         3
5        3        7        9        1        3        7        2        6        7        -2         2
6        1        8        6        0        4        9       -4        1        9        -4         1
  D73_3_DIP D81_1_DIP D82_2_DIP D83_3_DIP D91_1_BI D92_2_BI D101_1_BI D102_2_BI D111_1_BI D112_2_BI
1         3         2         8         2       -3        4         3         9         3         4
2         6         2         7         4        3        8         5         8         4         7
3         2         5        10         1        5       10         5        10         3         9
4         2         4         9         3        4        9         0         2         0         2
5         2         3         7         1       -1        3         3         6        -2         2
6         8         4         8         3        4        9         5        10         2         9
  D121_1_BI D122_2_BI total_iri promedio_falsaymisleading prediccioncompraspercprob
1         4         7        60                     2.750                  4.249759
2         5         4        63                     2.750                  4.404450
3         2         6        51                     2.875                  4.431635
4         0         2        48                     2.500                  5.143974
5        -3         2        38                     1.750                  3.765907
6         4        10        61                     3.875                  4.893797
  prediccioncomprasperc
1              4.474456
2              4.439994

3              4.521980
4              4.689385
5              3.762449
6              4.967286
```

Here is the raw dput() output:

```
    structure(list(ResponseId = c("R_25GEak825Ohmb9G", "R_1kT7u0PALDHV8H6", 
"R_2cpBb5Ifzj7lVGs", "R_sGqNUMTXTJzwC09", "R_2Cpixt9Z5FJkhg1", 
"R_3QFq50SZNs6CePA"), Edad = c(18, 20, 21, 20, 36, 18), Sex = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Male", "Female"), class = "factor"), 
    Genero = c("Femenino", "Femenino", "Femenino", "Masculino", 
    "Masculino", "Femenino"), Nacion = c("Colombia", "Colombia", 
    "Colombia", "Colombia", "Colombia", "Colombia"), Resid = c("Colombia", 
    "Colombia", "Colombia", "Colombia", "Colombia", "Colombia"
    ), Estrato_1 = c(7, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7), `Gastos salud` = c("Seguro privado", 
    "Seguro privado", "Seguro privado", "Seguro del Estado", 
    "Otro (especifique)", "Seguro privado"), Relig = c("Ninguna", 
    "Cristianismo (Catolicismo)", "Cristianismo (Catolicismo)", 
    "Cristianismo (Catolicismo)", "Cristianismo (Catolicismo)", 
    "Cristianismo (Catolicismo)"), PracticRel_2 = c(0, 2, 2, 
    2, 1, 4), AnEdu = c(15, 15, 19, 15, 17, 15), Q161 = c("Estudiante", 
    "Estudiante", "Estudiante", "Estudiante", "Empleado de tiempo completo", 
    "Estudiante"), Ecron = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Epsiq = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Q183 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Eneu = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Q184 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), NPviven = c("1", 
    "3", "4", "4", "3", "3"), Sustancias = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ), Pviven = c("Padres", "Padres,Hermanos", "Padres,Hermanos", 
    "Padres,Hermanos", "Pareja,Hijos", "Padres,Hermanos"), AdhAS = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), LevantarAS_1 = c(5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), CumplimAS_1 = c(6, 
    6, 6, 6, 3, 6), HorasFuera = c("Menos de una hora", "Menos de una hora", 
    "Menos de una hora", "Menos de una hora", "Entre cuatro y seis horas", 
    "Entre una y tres horas"), `Apoyo CV19_1` = c(1, 4, 6, 4, 
    5, 6), ContagUd = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), 
    ContagEC = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Prob_1_contagio = c(81, 81, 
    60, 4, 40, 79), Prob_2_familiar_contagio = c(100, 35, 80, 
    15, 40, 86), Prob_3_contagio_poblaciongeneral = c(87, 81, 
    80, 20, 60, 70), Caract_1 = c(4, 5, 4, 6, 2, 5), Caract_2 = c(2, 
    4, 4, 5, 1, 4), Inv_3 = c(1, 3, 1, 5, 2, 2), Caract_3 = c(6, 
    4, 6, 2, 5, 5), Caract_4 = c(4, 4, 6, 1, 4, 6), Caract_5 = c(5, 
    5, 6, 5, 3, 2), Caract_6 = c(4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 5), Caract_8 = c(5, 
    3, 2, 5, 3, 6), Caract_9 = c(5, 4, 6, 5, 4, 6), Caract_11 = c(3, 
    5, 1, 5, 1, 2), Caract_14 = c(2, 4, 6, 2, 1, 3), INV_15 = c(4, 
    5, 6, 6, 5, 5), Caract_15 = c(3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2), Caract_16 = c(5, 
    3, 6, 3, 2, 6), Caract_17 = c(5, 3, 6, 1, 2, 5), CompPan_1 = c(1, 
    4, 1, 1, 2, 2), CompPan_2 = c(6, 5, 1, 3, 2, 7), CompPan_3 = c(1, 
    8, 1, 2, 2, 3), CompPan_4 = c(5, 8, 3, 4, 3, 6), CompPan_5 = c(5, 
    8, 2, 3, 3, 2), CompPan_6 = c(7, 8, 4, 3, 2, 7), CercanPolDer_1 = c(8, 
    7, 6, 5, 5, 3), CercanPolIz_1 = c(2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 8), IDpol_1 = c(5, 
    5, 4, 4, 4, 3), PHQ_TOTAL = c(8, 4, 2, 3, 2, 7), GAD_TOTAL = c(6, 
    3, 3, 3, 2, 7), INTEROCEPCION_TOTAL = c(45, 44, 24, 17, 36, 
    41), BIS = c(19, 20, 17, 17, 21, 25), BAS_FUN_SEEKING = c(14, 
    10, 10, 9, 10, 6), BAS_REWARD_RESPONSIVENESS = c(19, 17, 
    19, 14, 17, 17), BAS_DRIVE = c(11, 14, 13, 8, 11, 13), BAS_TOTAL = c(44, 
    41, 42, 31, 38, 36), IRI_TOMA_DE_PERSPECTIVA = c(14, 18, 
    17, 16, 10, 16), IRI_MALESTAR_PERSONAL = c(13, 11, 4, 9, 
    11, 11), IRI_FANTASÍA = c(14, 14, 10, 11, 7, 16), IRI_PREOCUPACIÓN_EMPATICA = c(19, 
    20, 20, 12, 10, 18), RMET_TOTAL = c(7, 4, 10, 7, 10, 8), 
    PROMEDIO_TIEMPO_REACCION_RMET = c(2.41175, 3.3485, 3.26108333333333, 
    6.3905, 13.2126666666667, 4.21858333333333), PROMEDIO_CREENCIA_NFALSA_TODAS = c(2.8, 
    2.8, 2.4, 2.2, 1.8, 3.6), PROMEDIO_CREENCIA_NFALSA_CORONAVIRUS = c(2.66666666666667, 
    2.33333333333333, 2, 1.66666666666667, 1.33333333333333, 
    2.66666666666667), PROMEDIO_CREENCIA_NFALSA_OTRO = c(3, 3.5, 
    3, 3, 2.5, 5), PROMEDIO_TIEMPOREACCION_NFALSA = c(4.3438, 
    9.4222, 5.9734, 10.1448, 16.3196, 7.1954), PROMEDIO_CREENCIA_NVERDADERA_TODAS = c(3.33333333333333, 
    3, 3.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 1.33333333333333, 
    3.33333333333333), PROMEDIO_CREENCIA_NVERDADERA_CORONAVIRUS = c(5, 
    4, 6, 5, 1, 6), PROMEDIO_CREENCIA_NVERDADERA_OTRO = c(5, 
    5, 5, 3, 3, 4), PROMEDIO_TIEMPOREACCION_NVERDADERA = c(5.644, 
    7.043, 8.0265, 4.0495, 32.24, 9.583), PROMEDIO_CREENCIA_NMISLEADING_TODAS = c(2.66666666666667, 
    2.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 3, 1.66666666666667, 
    4.33333333333333), PROMEDIO_TIEMPOREACCION_NMISLEADING = c(5.72666666666667, 
    12.0123333333333, 5.753, 4.96966666666667, 15.233, 30.0456666666667
    ), PROMEDIO_DILEMAS_BI_BIENOMAL_CORONAVIRUS = c(1, 4, 4.33333333333333, 
    1.33333333333333, 0, 3.66666666666667), PROMEDIO_DILEMAS_BI_ACTUARIGUAL_CORONAVIRUS = c(5.66666666666667, 
    7.66666666666667, 9.66666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 
    9.33333333333333), DILEMA_BI_CONTROL_BIENOMAL = c(4, 5, 2, 
    0, -3, 4), DILEMA_BI_CONTROL_ACTUARIGUAL = c(7, 4, 6, 2, 
    2, 10), PROMEDIO_DILEMAS_BI_BIENOMAL_JUNTOS = c(1.75, 4.25, 
    3.75, 1, -0.75, 3.75), PROMEDIO_DILEMAS_BI_ACTUARIGUAL_JUNTOS = c(6, 
    6.75, 8.75, 3.75, 3.25, 9.5), PROMEDIO_DILEMAS_DI_BIENOMAL = c(0.5, 
    1.83333333333333, 0.5, 1.66666666666667, 0.833333333333333, 
    0.166666666666667), PROMEDIO_DILEMAS_DI_ACTUARIGUAL = c(6.66666666666667, 
    7.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 5, 4.83333333333333, 
    5.16666666666667), PROMEDIO_DILEMAS_DI_DANO = c(5.66666666666667, 
    6.16666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 5.5, 5.66666666666667, 
    7), TIEMPOREACCION_DILEMAS_DI = c(12.1405, 9.13066666666666, 
    6.99833333333333, 1.85783333333333, 19.0143333333333, 11.6336666666667
    ), TIEMPOREACCION_DILEMAS_BI = c(7.899, 9.9955, 9.25175, 
    2.84125, 32.8285, 16.92), PROMEDIO_DI_SINPOL_BIENOMAL = c(0.2, 
    1.2, -1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.2), PROMEDIO_DI_SINPOL_ACTUARIGUAL = c(7, 
    8, 4.25, 4.5, 5, 5.5), PROMEDIO_DI_SINPOL_DANO = c(7.25, 
    6.75, 7.25, 7, 7.75, 7.75), COMPRAS_COVID19 = c(4.16666666666667, 
    6.83333333333333, 2, 2.66666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 
    4.5), PERCEPCION_RIESGO_TOTAL = c(39, 37, 42, 38, 26, 46), 
    PERCEPCION_RIESGO_INDICE = c(3.9, 3.7, 4.2, 3.8, 2.6, 4.6
    ), PROB_CONTAGIO_TOTAL = c(89.3333333333333, 65.6666666666667, 
    73.3333333333333, 13, 46.6666666666667, 78.3333333333333), 
    PROMEDIO_DILEMASPOLITICOS_BIENOMAL = c(1, 2.5, 4, 4, 0.5, 
    0), PROMEDIO_DILEMASPOLITICOS_ACTUARIGUAL = c(6, 7, 8.5, 
    6, 4.5, 4.5), PROMEDIO_DILEMASPOLITICOS_DANO = c(2.5, 5, 
    1.5, 2.5, 1.5, 5.5), D31_1_DI = c(-2, 3, -3, 0, -2, 4), D32_2_DI = c(4, 
    9, 3, 3, 4, 9), D33_3_DI = c(9, 7, 8, 8, 8, 7), D41_1_DI = c(-1, 
    1, 0, 0, 3, 1), D42_2_DI = c(7, 8, 6, 5, 7, 8), D43_3_DI = c(7, 
    9, 7, 8, 9, 6), D51_1_DI = c(5, 0, 1, 4, 1, 0), D52_2_DI = c(10, 
    7, 5, 7, 3, 4), D53_3_DI = c(4, 4, 6, 3, 7, 9), D61_1_DI = c(-1, 
    2, -3, -2, 2, -4), D62_2_DI = c(7, 8, 3, 3, 6, 1), D63_3_DI = c(9, 
    7, 8, 9, 7, 9), D71_1_DIP = c(0, 3, 3, 4, -2, -4), D72_2_DIP = c(4, 
    7, 7, 3, 2, 1), D73_3_DIP = c(3, 6, 2, 2, 2, 8), D81_1_DIP = c(2, 
    2, 5, 4, 3, 4), D82_2_DIP = c(8, 7, 10, 9, 7, 8), D83_3_DIP = c(2, 
    4, 1, 3, 1, 3), D91_1_BI = c(-3, 3, 5, 4, -1, 4), D92_2_BI = c(4, 
    8, 10, 9, 3, 9), D101_1_BI = c(3, 5, 5, 0, 3, 5), D102_2_BI = c(9, 
    8, 10, 2, 6, 10), D111_1_BI = c(3, 4, 3, 0, -2, 2), D112_2_BI = c(4, 
    7, 9, 2, 2, 9), D121_1_BI = c(4, 5, 2, 0, -3, 4), D122_2_BI = c(7, 
    4, 6, 2, 2, 10), total_iri = c(60, 63, 51, 48, 38, 61), promedio_falsaymisleading = c(2.75, 
    2.75, 2.875, 2.5, 1.75, 3.875), prediccioncompraspercprob = c(`1` = 4.24975892576113, 
    `2` = 4.40445037029013, `3` = 4.43163539588384, `4` = 5.14397435590305, 
    `5` = 3.76590707825915, `6` = 4.8937968160894), prediccioncomprasperc = c(`1` = 4.47445595202732, 
    `2` = 4.4399943212902, `3` = 4.52198006754018, `4` = 4.68938453833302, 
    `5` = 3.7624488758014, `6` = 4.96728571465517)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Something is going wrong with your modelling and you're getting missing values for every row somewhere in your output.  So altering plot parameters wont help.  You need to fix your data. vRather than running 300 models, run just one.  Then read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and provide us with your input data and any other information we need to help you effectively.

Comment: Hello Limey, I just edited this post with the data and reproducible code. Thank you!

Comment: Your Google drive folder is private.  Don't fix it.  Instead, please `dput()` a small sample of your data that is sufficient to reproduce your problem.  Please help us to help you.

Comment: Hello Limey, I just edited this post with the dput() outcome as data frame and raw. Thanks for your help!